# e-mail read/undread mail

Tags: email, pop3

I write simple own pop3 server. I use thunderbird mail client for testing. I have directory where set mails. Mail message - 1 text file with message. When i connect to my server with thunderbird, it download letters, if i click get mail it's again download same messages and mark it how new. How can i explain to mail client what messages new and what already read?

Thank you.

Comment: I do not think this is possible with POP.

Comment: You either want to `DELE` messages from the server or track the ones you've seen already via caching their `UIDL` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POP3 does not have any way of specifying from server to client if a message has been read, is new or any other information about the message. Use IMAP for that purpose.

A POP3 client will locally record if the message has been read (locally).

Comment: Thank you for reply. But i try to connect to other mail services, gmail for example, it's send me only new message every time by pop3.

Comment: Now i understand. Client deleting message from pop3 server after downloading. Thank you.

Comment: POP3 does not specify what the server is allowed to do, when a client has fetched an email. When you have downloaded an email from the Gmail server, it will actually delete the mail for all other POP3 sessions, UNLESS you reset the gmail settings (on gmail) or use a special recent: username. So it does not show you "new" messages, it shoes messages that no other POP3 client has downloaded. You can do the same if you want. If you do that, be sure to read up on the CAPA EXPIRE command, where you can tell your POP3 client you will delete it. It is not the client that deletes the mail with Gmail.

Comment: @dkarp This was exactly what I was refering to with "A POP3 client will locally record if the message has been read (locally)." A bit vague maybe, but I do not think I deserve a downvote for that. But again, there is no way to explain to a client if a message is new or old. The client must locally hold such information itself.

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for not explaining *how to do it* via POP.  Just saying "track on your own" is not helpful...

Answer (score 1):

If your POP server supports [the UIDL command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939#section-7) (and most do), you can put together a local database in your POP client to track the persistent UIDL values for messages you've downloaded.  After you authenticate to the POP server, issue `UIDL`.  Messages whose UIDL is already in your database can be safely ignored.  For any messages whose UIDL *isn't* in your database, issue `RETR` to fetch the message and then store its UIDL.

Alternatively, issue `DELE` commands to delete messages after they've been downloaded via `RETR`.